# Automatically take specific data out of specific emails and put it into an excel form

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm completely new to VBA.

Is it possible to write some code that would search for emails from a specific sender and search inside that email for a specific line in a table, which it would then put into an already existing excel form?

Any advice on where to get started learning this or if it's even possible would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would start by using google and doing a search for: stack overflow vba search email   Then use the macro recorder in excel.  Then when you have code and get  stuck come back and post your question.

Comment: [Getting Started on Outlook VBA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is possible to make that. You have three types to search something like that.

You have the `View`, `AdvancedSearch` and the `Explorer.Search`. 
The `View` is only for one folder.
The Filter for the `View` is called *Distributed Authoring Search and Location* (DASL). Here is a good link for that filter type: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms874577(v=exchg.65).aspx 
The `AdvancedSearch` is like the `View`, but you can search over all folders and all nameboxes. BUT there is problem! When you use `AdvancedSearch` you have to create an folder and in this folder are your results. The filter of the folder is unchangebel, so after creading you cant change anything. The folder will update Automaticly if there are new Mail or something else. The `AdvancedSearch` uses the same filter as `View`.
The last one is the `Explorer.Search`. With that search you can search like the `AdvancedSearch`, but you have not to create an folder. This one uses the *Advanced Query Syntax* (AQS). Here is a good link for that filter type: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc513841(v=office.12).aspx 
 
Each of the searches can filter for all typs of objects. So you can Search for things in Mails.
Text in mails is Called in..
- DASL **textdescription**.
- AQS **contents**. 
 
I hope I could help you by starting.